# Change the class of a different button when hovering a different element

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass

I have a file upload field that I have styled by dropping the opacity to 0 so that the div containing the style can be seen through this.

[image: styling]

The styling is not far different form a default file upload but at least this way it looks the same cross browser.

HTML:

```
<div id="up_field">
        <div id="select_files">
            <div>Select Files to upload...</div>
            <input id="file_over" type="button" value="Select Files" />
        </div>
        <div id="select_field"><input type="file" id="file" name="file[]"  multiple /></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
#up_field{
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
#up_field div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
#up_field #select_files{
    line-height:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:15px;
}
#up_field #select_files div{
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:2%;
    width:60%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:25px;
    font-size:12px;
}
#up_field #select_files input{
    width:33%;
    padding:0;
    outline:0;
    marign:0;
    height:100%;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    float:right;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: -1px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
.front_hover{
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
#up_field #select_files input:active{
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
#up_field #select_field{
    opacity:0;
}
#file{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Normally I would set the button (#file_over) with the hover in css, sort of like:

```
#file_over:hover{
etc
}
```

But instead I have created this as a second class (.front_hover) to use with a jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#file').hover(function(event){
         $('#file_over').addClass('front_hover');
    },function(){
        $('#file_over').removeClass('front_hover');
    });
});
```

But this does nothing at all, however if I change the CSS property for example .css('width','100px')  the width of the button does change. Is there something in the CSS that is preventing this form happen or does anybody know a better way of achieving this effect?

Comment: Could you please add a jsfiddle ???

Comment: @Joseph, you're not the only one, so please don't take this personally, but lately I'm starting to wonder what's going on with all these requests for fiddles. The code is in the question, you can make a fiddle yourself in three clicks if you really have to, so why bother the questioner?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I like your point but here you go anyway [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6kUu/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of using just `.file_over` you will need to use:

`#up_field #select_files input.file_over`

to declare your hover styles

This is to do with [css specifity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/C6kUu/1/)

Comment: Thankyou, I knew I was close but didn't relise about targeted the css in that way though

Answer (score 0):

You have two `<div id="select_field">` next to each other. Delete the second `<div>` and add :`hover` state in your CSS: `#up_field #select_files input#file_over:hover {color: red}`